# What is the preferred way to store per device MAC and static IP on a Xilinx FPGA?

Tags: ethernet, xilinx, artix-series-fpga

I've been writing some Ethernet handling code for Artix-7 FPGAs. As I said in the question I want to, on per device basis, store a device MAC and device IP address. In other words I would like to be able to write these separately from the bitstream instead of building a new bitstream for every device. An unfortunately complication is that the prototype boards we have do not have some sort of EEPROM attached so I am stuck with the stuff available on the FPGA, and a few other things.

With some digging I have two possibilities. One seems promising, the other quite ugly.

1. Use the `EFUSE_USR` a 32 bit vector of efuses I can program.
2. Loading the assigned MAC and IP into the configuration memory, "above" the bit stream. The SPI memory is 128Mb and the FPGA bitstream is 78Mb so there is plenty of space.

With 1 the upside is that getting at the data is dead simple, just instantiate a macro and boom, done. But I think the downside is two-fold. First, I can't really reprogram it after the first time. Second, because it's 32-bits, it only stores parts of the desired MAC / static IP addresses so some components of the addresses have to be hard coded still.

With 2 the upside is that the full MAC, IP, and a good deal more, can be stored all at once. Also, it's completely reprogramable, I can rewrite it at will up to the limit of the NAND gates. The downside is that getting to it is significantly more effort.

Are there alternatives that I am overlooking?
Am I overlooking anything that makes the second option easier to retrieve the data for?

Comment: Another option if you don't mind re-running just the "write_bitstream" step is the USR_ACCESS register. https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1232-bitstream-id-with-usr_access.pdf

Comment: There are plenty of FPGA applications that use the leftover configuration space for nonvolatile application data -- in fact, it's quite common. Some applications put an entire filesystem there. Some applications can do field updates of the bitstream, with redundant copies for safety. Xilinx has IP that can access the config memory for pretty much any of the config memory options. For example, if your config memory is QSPI, there's a module for that. Remember, many of the pins used to config the chip become user I/O after config is finished.

Comment: @ks0ze Thanks for letting me know about that register! I didn't have a clue it was there.

Comment: @DaveTweed I didn't see that module in my first look through the IP catalog for A200T-2 FPGAs. I see the AXI Quad SPI module but, 1) I am trying to avoid AXI for now and 2) the module still leaves actually "talking" to the memory to me. Is there a different name I should be looking under?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "talking" to the memory. In what way do you expect the data to be presented?

Comment: @DaveTweed I was hoping for something like: "I give an address and after X ticks I get the word at that address" as opposed to the: "Write a state machine to generate the appropriate commands to read the addresses and handle the replies." i.e. I was hoping for something that would abstract the SPI chip into something vaguely resembling a single port block ram with lots of latency. Also, as stated before, I'm trying to avoid AXI for now, the learning curve I am am climbing is steep enough without adding that. That said, I want to thank you for telling me using the cfg memory for data is common.

Comment: @ks0ze if you write your comment into a brief answer I would be more than happy to select it. I think I am going to use the USR_ACCESS to set the static IP and, for now, use the device DNA to set most of a locally administered MAC address.